# Angular8 ngx-bootstrap doesn't compile with --prod

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

Using

```
angular cli 8.3.8, 
bootstrap 4.4.4
ngx-bootstrap 5.6.1,
```

Everything works great in development.  But when I compile with --prod, I get the following errors below.  We must get the --prod to work.  The datepicker looks and works great, don't want to have to remove it.

```
ERROR in node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker.d.ts.BsDatepickerContainerComponent.html(60,7): Property 'chosenRange' does not exist on type 'BsDatepickerContainerComponent'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker.d.ts.BsDatepickerContainerComponent.html(62,7): Property 'setRangeOnCalendar' does not exist on type 'BsDatepickerContainerComponent'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker.d.ts.BsDatepickerInlineContainerComponent.html(60,7): Property 'chosenRange' does not exist on type 'BsDatepickerInlineContainerComponent'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker.d.ts.BsDatepickerInlineContainerComponent.html(62,7): Property 'setRangeOnCalendar' does not exist on type 'BsDatepickerInlineContainerComponent'.
```

Comment: This question is hard to answer, as there are a lot of important details missing. Try to put yourself in the shoes of those who know nothing about your problem. Make sure to [edit] your question to include all **relevant** content. Providing a [mcve] will increase your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: I generally occurs by unmatched version. change. Change  ngx-bootstrap version

Comment: Minimal reproducibility:

ng new myApp
npm i ngx-bootstrap

Use anywhere:
    <input type="text" bsDatepicker #dp="bsDatepicker"

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, try to downgrade ngx-bootstrap version to '5.1.0'.

Use the command `npm install ngx-bootstrap@5.1.0`

Answer (score 1):

change at package.json to "ngx-bootstrap": "5.6.2" and run npm i.